# Decorator Stop AutoRun

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm trying to implement a decorator with parameters.

Here's my actual code:

```
def transactional_function(read_only=False):
    """
    A simple wrapper to ensure that the desired function will always runs
    inside a transaction, so we don't have to pollute our code with a bunch of
    run_as_transactions.
    """
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            in_transaction = getattr(_thread_local_data, "is_in_transaction", False)

            if in_transaction:
                result = func(*args, **kw)
            else:
                if read_only:
                    return run_as_readonly(func, *args, **kw)
                else:
                    return run_as_transaction(func, *args, **kw)
            return result
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

However this auto-runs upon function declaration.

So in theory what I need is only a wrapper, but I wish I could add arguments to the decorated function, for instance.

```
decorated_function(standard_arg, read_only=True)
```

Is that somehow possible? I could only implement wrappers with no parameters or decorators that auto run with parameters.

Comment: What you posted would not auto-run the decorated function; let's see an example of an actual use of this decorator, maybe something is wrong there. The wrapper can take whatever parameters you want, it's not obligated to pass them on to the wrapped function.

Comment: As @jasonharper pointed-out, the code your question won't run the function being decorated — so something else is causing that to occur. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you started on a wrong way: what you want is not to add a parameter to the decorator but to the decorated function. It is rather tricky in the general case, because you will have to add that parameter to the decorated function and remove it before calling the original function unless it already exists in the original function.

Here is a simplified version that only displays the read_only state and calls the original function:

```
import inspect
from functools import wraps

def transactional_function(func):
    sig = inspect.signature(func)   # extract the original signature
    params = sig.parameters
    if 'read_only' in params:
        change = False              # read_only already exists, just note that
    else:
        change = True
        # let us add a new keyword only parameter 'read_only'
        params = list(params.values())
        params.append(inspect.Parameter('read_only',
                        inspect.Parameter.KEYWORD_ONLY))
        # re-order the parameter list
        params.sort(key=lambda x: {
            inspect.Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD: 0,
            inspect.Parameter.POSITIONAL_ONLY: 0,
            inspect.Parameter.VAR_POSITIONAL:1,
            inspect.Parameter.KEYWORD_ONLY:2,
            inspect.Parameter.VAR_KEYWORD:3}[x.kind])
        # and set that new parameter list in the signature
        sig = sig.replace(parameters = params)
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        read_only = kwargs.get('read_only', False)
        # remove the parameter if it was added by the decorator
        if change and ('read_only' in kwargs):
            del kwargs['read_only']
        print('read_only', read_only)       # add your logic here
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    # update the signature of the decorated function
    if change:
        inner.__signature__ = sig
    return inner
```

Demo:

```
>>> @transactional_function
def foo(bar):
    return bar * 2

>>> foo(2)
read_only False
4
>>> foo(2, read_only=False)
read_only False
4
>>> foo(2, read_only=True)
read_only True
4
```

and with a more complex signature:

```
>>> @transactional_function
def foo2(a, *args, **kwargs):
    return a
>>> foo2(2, read_only=True)
read_only True
2
```